# Proof of an intuition for equivalent definitions?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

I have a very strong intuition about the equivalency of the following definitions for Cauchy sequences:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists M \in \mathbb{N} : k, l \geq M \implies d(x_k, x_l) < \varepsilon $$

$$ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : n \geq N \implies \exists \varepsilon > 0, x : x_n \in B(x, \varepsilon) $$

The way I see it, you can potentially (and temporarily!) 'fix' either $k$ or $l$ in the first definition and use it as a center for the ball of the second.  In this way, you could suppose that the ball actually has a diameter of$\varepsilon$, with 'nearby' points $x_k$ and $x_l$.

In the second definition, saying that $x_n \in B(x, \varepsilon)$ is equivalent to saying the distance from $x$ to $x_n$ is less than $\varepsilon$, which would relate it back to the first definition.

I know beyond a doubt that these definitions must be equivalent, but I can't seem to formalize my intuitions in a way that is irrefutable (e.g. neither $x_k$ nor $x_l$ need be in every $B(x, \varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon$, thus the need for 'temporarily').

Is there a better way of saying what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually *not* equivalent. Your second definition simply says that the sequence is (eventually) bounded. The first implies the second, but the second does not imply the first.

For example, consider the sequence $x_n:=(-1)^n$. This is certainly not Cauchy--try it for any $\epsilon\in(0,2).$ However, for any $N$ and all $n\ge N$, it is certainly the case that $x_n\in B(0,2)$.

The big difference, here, is that the definition of Cauchy allows us to take $\epsilon$ to be **any** positive number, and still see that, for big enough $n$, all the $x_n$ are within $\epsilon$ of each other. In your definition, we're only guaranteed that all $x_n$ will (eventually) lie within *some* $\epsilon$-neighborhood of some point, but we have no control over how big this neighborhood is allowed to be.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I need to be *much* more careful in my reading.  This is a good example of the importance of quantifiers, at any rate.  Now I just feel dumb.  XD